# What is the maximum amount of time I should leave between resin layer?

Tags: epoxy-resin

I want to set micro diorama using tabletop gaming pieces in clear resin.

I will put in an opaque base layer for the ground. Set up a scene on top of it and then fill this second layer with clear resin, the add a third sky layer on top to cap it off.

What is the maximum time I can leave each layer to ensure that the next layer properly adheres to it?

For example, can I do three layers over three seperate days with 24 hour between each layer. Or do I need to finish the entire piece in a single day?

Comment: I don't have the stats, but anecdotally, I've gone far longer than recommended between layers (think months, not days), and everything's adhered just fine on that project.

Answer (score 5):

Resins differ but most recommend that you apply additional layers when the previous layer is firm but tacky to the touch.  This can be minutes to hours after an initial pour but usually less than 24 hours in any case.

Some resins allow for pouring over a previously cured layer, but recommend that you scratch the hardened surface to "rough it up" so that the new resin has something to hold onto.  For those kinds of resins, scratch marks and even the fog caused by sanding disappear when the new wet resin is applied.  Watch a Youtube video on sanding resin between pours to see it happen.  It is a little unbelievable but I've done it myself during an interrupted pour and it worked

Also, be aware that thick layers of resin give off a lot of heat while they are hardening.  If any of the gaming pieces you are using are plastic, then I would suggest lots of thin (1/4 inch) layers rather than drowning them in several inches of atmosphere all at once.